# Upload the same file several times

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to upload the same file several times for each user that is selected.

For example, if you selected 3 users, the uploaded file need to be moved to the user folder.

MY CODE:

```
$subDir = $_POST['curr_user'];
   $usuarios = explode(',', $subDir);

   if (count($usuarios) > 1) {
        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {
               $usFolder = file_exists ( $upload_dir['basedir'].'/file_uploads/'.$usuario);

               if (!$usFolder) {
                   mkdir ( $upload_dir['basedir'].'/file_uploads/'. $usuario, 0777 , true );
                   chmod($upload_dir['basedir'].'/file_uploads/'. $usuario,0777);
               }


               $target_path = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/file_uploads/';

               $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);


               if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

                    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . "userfile_data", array( 'id'=> '','user_id'=>$usuario,'category'=>$_POST['curr_cat'],'filename'=>basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] )));


              }

         }
   }
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Don't move the file, then. moving it by necessity REMOVES it from the original place, so it won't be there for the next user you process. **COPY** it instead, then manually delete it once all users are processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to 'move' it many times.

Unfortunately there is no 'copy_uploaded_file', so instead you can:

- Move the uploaded file into a temporary directory first
- Then in your loop COPY that file into the target directories per user.
- Once finished, clean up the original file.